# can Illustrator-files with raster images keep jpg compression?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, file-size, raster

Is there a way to keep the jpg compression in .ai-files with embeded raster graphics?

Ok so I had an .ai-file of 2800kB.

I pasted a 2MB jpg in the document and the file is now 16MB.

So I guess the JPG is converted to some pixel graphic so transforms etc. could be done easily. And maybe also saved an extra time in the PDF-preview.

However I find this a wast of space, since I mostly use jpgs as visualisation/illustration. Is there a lighter way?

Comment: Try to link them externally... I'm not sure if Illustrator allows that.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, you can do this. You can either keep them embedded and turn off `Create PDF Compatible File`, or you can link to the original files (and still turn off `Create PDF Compatible File`).

#### Linked files

If you place an image using `File` → `Place`, it will link to the image by default. You can check this by opening `Window` → `Links` — if the `Embed Image(s)` action is available, it’s linked.

[image: Illustrator Links panel]

However, you’ll notice if you now save your file, it‘s bigger. That’s probably because you have `Create PDF Compatible File` turned on. If you do, `Save As`, and turn it off.

[image: Create PDF compatible file in Illustrator]

#### Size comparison

I’ve saved some test files with linked and embedded versions. The image and linked file add up to roughly the same size as the embedded file.

[image: Files in Finder]

426KB + 924KB = 1,350KB (~1.4MB)

Comment: good to know that by disabling pdf compatibility teh AI file is nolonger possible to easily embed in indesign for example.

Comment: @joojaa Oh, yep, it definitely comes at a price. It’s best to leave it on, if you can! You also lose the preview in the Finder.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I still don't quite get my own calculation.
2800 + 2000 = 16000????

Comment: @agiopnl I assume there’s multiple copies of the image and vector data inside the file. I think “PDF compatibility” means there’s a separate PDF portion that’s a duplicate of the Ai data.

Comment: Probably something like that, still doesn't add up very well :p